# Decrypt Asp Membership password with validation SHA1 and decryption AES with HASHED password format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, aes, sha1

I have an asp web application an I am using .net Web Security library to create users with method 
`MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, out MembershipCreateStatus status);`

Also I have bellow settings in my `Web.config` file

**machineKey**

```
<machineKey validationKey="52556EFC87C01645626E448147EDCE5AFD0BAC7D6C2E23FEDC789ED09C18ADBB81D52DDE60EDCC548CD4818249B197B364C2E7E287855E3F0C6BBB2A08F90CD5" decryptionKey="2A0BEA061F4A2AAAE75D6D4B0F97231F890332D2B10AED84AF6D0C5B09C38605" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
```

And

```
<add applicationName="MyApplication" name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="5" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"/>
```

I would like to ask if is it possible to decrypt the Asp Membership passwords if yes how can I do ?

If someone needs more information please let me know

Comment: No it's not possible in a reasonable enough time.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen Feel free to create a negative answer if you are sure, but please explain why. It seems to me that it may depend a bit on the password if everything is stored locally. I mean 5 characters minimum is not much. Then again, I don't know squat, zip, nada, zilch about ASP.

Comment: Simply because the password is not encrypted when it is stored in the database. It is hashed and hashes are designed not to be decryptable. If the hashing function is properly configured then it will take more time to find the correct password than the universe is old.

Answer (score 1):

By default, **SqlMembershipProvider** uses **SHA1**.

**SqlMembershipProvider  Hash** is nothing to do with **machineKey** tag. ***FYI:***  **validation** of machineKey is used for **ViewState encryption**.

It just a coincident that validation of machineKey defined as **SHA1**. ***FYI:*** you don't even need to explicit set it because SHA1 is [default value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.85).aspx).

*(Note: MembershipProvider uses machine key if password format is encrypted.)*

### SHA1

You cannot decrypt the hashed password, but you can find collision. However, it estimated cost of [$2.77M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Attacks) to break a single hash value by renting CPU power from cloud servers.